Find "$anyvalue and $anyvalue" replace first with "____" and second with first value
I'd like to find and replace "$xxxxx and $yyyyy". Dollar signs are constant. The numbers can be thousands or millions. The replace will look like "$____ and $xxxxx" where the first value is copied to replace the second value and a space holder of underscores is inserted for the first value. This would be within a Word file of 10 to 100 pages lone. The instances would be scattered throughout the various paragraphs.
I don't know where to start with this. I haven't found anything like it online.
